# Traversing nested class in XDocument to JSON

Tags: c#, http, linq-to-xml

In a C# API, I receive a xml response that I need to convert to JSON in order to return it to my front-end client app. I can't quite figure out how to convert the nested descendant into the nested class.

I have two C# classes truncated below.

```
public class DetailsKey
{
  public string Status {get; set;}
  public string ErrorMessage {get; set;}
  public string AmountApproved {get; set;}
  public PaymentDetails PaymentDetails {get; set;}
}

public class PaymentDetails
{
  public string Id {get;set;}
  public string PaymentType {get;set;}
  public string Customer {get;set;}
}
```

After I get a response I parse it as follows:

```
XDocument xd = XDocument.Parse(result);

var detResponse = xd.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "DetailsKey").Select(x => new DetailsKey()
{
  Status = (string)x.Element(x.Name.Namespace + "Status"),
  ErrorMessage = (string)x.Element(x.Name.Namespace + "ErrorMessage"),
  AmountApproved = (string)x.Element(x.Name.Namespace + "AmountApproved"),
  PaymentDetails = x.Descendants("PaymentDetails").Select(p => new PaymentDetails()
   {
     PaymentDetail = x.Descendants("PaymentDetail").Select(pd => new PaymentDetail(){
       Id = (string)pd.Element(pd.Name.Namespace + "Id"),
       ErrorMessage = (string)pd.Element(pd.Name.Namespace + "ErrorMessage"),
       PaymentType = (string)pd.Element(pd.Name.Namespace + "PaymentType"),
       Customer = (string)pd.Element(pd.Name.Namespace + "Customer")
       }).FirstOrDefault(),
    }).FirstOrDefault(),
 }).FirstOrDefault();
```

If I comment out the "PaymentDetails = ..." there are no errors. But when I try to parse the PaymentDetails descendant I get errors. What is the proper way to parse a descendant and put it into a nested class.

Here is a sample of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<DetailsKey>
  <Status>APPROVED</Status>
  <AmountApproved>7.65</AmountApproved>
  <ErrorMessage/>
  <PaymentDetails>
   <PaymentDetail>
    <Id>12345</Id>
    <ErrorMessage/>
    <PaymentType>SALE</PaymentType>
    <Customer>John Smith</Customer>
   </PaymentDetail>
  </PaymentDetails>
</DetailsKey>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Is payment details a list or a singleValue? also try doing a firstOrDefault()

Comment: It's a single value.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Post sample of Xml.  You should be using Xml Serialization to take response an put into classes, unless the Xml has lots of descendants and you want to flatten results.  The take Classes and convert to JSON.

Comment: Adding a FirstorDefault() eliminated the error, but now it's returning null. Example:

    {
      "status": "Approved"... (other elements)
       "paymentDetails": null
    }

But I think I see the error. Let me try to fix it before posting a sample of the xml.

Comment: I added a sample of the XML and a fuller example of how I'm traversing it because I am getting a null response in PaymentDetails.

Answer (score 1):

There were two problems. First as @mahlatse suggested in the first comment, I needed to add firstOrDefault() to each of the nested descendants. Once added the error was eliminated. But I was still getting a null value for the nested descendants.

The second fix included adding:

```
.Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "nameofElement")
```

before the Select call, and eliminating the nameOfElement string in Descendants().

Once fixed, the conversion of xml to JSON worked.